# Issue in getting list of contact in Dynamic365 CRM using REST API with access token

Tags: dynamics-crm, postman, dynamics-365, dynamics-crm-365, dynamics-crm-webapi

I created the postman collection to the fetching list of contact from Dynamic365. I am not sure what is an issue with the below postman screenshot. I am always getting a blank response.

[image: Postman screenshot with header parameter]

[image: Authorization parameter]

Answer (score 0):

If you look at your postman output area at right side it clearly says 401: unauthorized error.
That means from whichever account you are calling webapi for your Crm, you do not possess right to access the system.

I would recommend you go through below blogpost and configure as mentioned. You will get correct data at end.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/customer-engagement/developer/webapi/setup-postman-environment

Comment: I tried but it's not working for me. Check the attached screenshot for mo details : [link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1zDdwlZ--1Iu-yPeCL1dmPRlD-PLPVIjo/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: I think you are not using correct authentication. You need to select oauth2 as request type. Btw did you register your app in azure AD and then gave it proper access as mentioned in docs.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the settings as it is from this [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/developer/common-data-service/webapi/setup-postman-environment), including `clientid = 51f81489-12ee-4a9e-aaae-a2591f45987d` which is open for any crm online instance.

You should not use `Bearer Token`, use `OAuth 2.0` in authorization tab, then generate the token.

[Read my another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60194687/7920473).