# Accessing Dynamics 365 API using Postman

Tags: api, dynamics-crm, postman, dynamics-365, dynamics-crm-webapi

I am trying to make an API request against a Dynamics 365 API account using Postman. I have the following credentials but I do not know what headers to use to authenticate.

I have the following ...

1. Consumer Key
2. Consumer Secret
3. Redirect Uri
4. Authorize Redirect URL
5. HTTP Method = POST
6. Access Token Service Endpoint

What headers do I need to set in Postman to get access to the API?

I have read articles and seen some examples but they all have different data than I do. For example in the screen capture below there is a username and password in addition to a Consumer Key (client_id) and Consumer Secret (client_secret).

[image]

I do understand that I need to obtain a `Bearer token` first before making the API call. It is obtaining this token that is confusing me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simply follow this [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/developer/common-data-service/webapi/setup-postman-environment) to setup the Postman for Dynamics web API, even the ready-made `clientid = 51f81489-12ee-4a9e-aaae-a2591f45987d` will work for any CRM online instance for testing purpose. You can use your customer provided `clientid` as well.

`url` should be `https://crmdev.crm.dynamics.com`
`authurl` should be `https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/authorize?resource={{url}}`

First create an environment in Postman:

> [image]

Use `OAuth 2.0` in `Authorization` tab, and `Get New Access Token`.

[image]

Comment: can I quickly ask related to Postman and webapi. Whenever I try to follow the doc mentioned, I end up with 404 Error. I did saw some blogs mentioning the issue and solution but somehow I could not overcome. Could you please add some insight for it, if you faced this issue?

Comment: @AnkUser I faced some issues when there’s a firewall rule or AD security group access for permissions, otherwise it’s straight forward. Even I tried yesterday for the first time in a new laptop, no issues.

Comment: @ArunVinoth Should the values added to the environment persist to the "Get New Access Token", because there don't seem to be. When I click "Get New Access Token" I am prompted to enter the same data I setup in the environment

Comment: @webworm make sure your just created environment is chosen in top right dropdown “test01” in second screenshot before generating token

Comment: @ArunVinoth Thanks for the response. I find that I am being prompted to enter a username and password through a popup in Postman. I did not expect this. Is that because "implicit" is being used? If I have a `Client Secret` shouldn't I be using the `Grant Type` of `Authorization Code`?

Comment: @webworm this is just for postman testing, coding is different, where you can silently get token using clientid & secret

Comment: @ArunVinoth what I am looking to do is test getting data back from an API call using Postman. I want to make sure it works before I write the code. Shouldn't I be able to do this, in Postman, if I know the `Client Secret`?

Comment: @webworm you are not the first one to do this :) believe me. It may work, but I never tried it. If someone tried, let’s wait for them..

Comment: @webworm see this - https://www.toolsqa.com/postman/oauth-2-0-authorization-with-postman/ its totally possible, but client secret is confidential, I may not put it in postman config & keep it open for vulnerability.. pls upvote/accept this answer if its helpful

Comment: @ArunVinoth completed all the steps mentioned in Dcoumentation of answer. Got Token successfully as well, one addition had to `oauth2AllowImplicitFlow` to true.
But testing connection with `{{webapiurl}}WhoAmI` gives 401 error. I am kind of always stuck here.

Comment: Same situation as @AnkUser. Was able to obtain token but when using token to make API call a 401 is returned. Created new SO question for it. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60217420/getting-back-401-from-dynamics-365-despite-being-issued-valid-token