# Getting back 401 from Dynamics 365 despite being issued valid token

Tags: api, dynamics-crm, postman, dynamics-365

I am attempting to rewrite a client app that currently connects to Dynamics 365 using JavaScript

```
let URL = "https://<company-name>.operations.dynamics.com/data/FinancialDimensionValues?cross-company=true";
let  body = '';
var headers = {'Content-Type':'application/json'};
let response = ai.https.authorizedRequest(URL, 'GET', body, headers);
```

Currently this JavaScript application works and gets back JSON data. I am attempting to rewrite this application using C#. I am first starting with Postman to make sure I have all the authentication steps in place before moving on the writing the C# code.

Using Postman I am able to successfully obtain a JWT token using the "Client Credentials" flow where I pass the Client ID and the Client Secret to the Access Token Request URL. However, when trying to access an API endpoint within Dynamics 365 I receive back an HTTP 401 even though I am passing the JWT access token properly.

**Here is the Access Token Request URL:**

`https://login.microsoftonline.com/722b0db7-9629-4304-92a0-dfb4a1debe62/oauth2/token?resource=https://<company-domain-here>.dynamics.com`

I am thinking that I must be authenticating properly or I would not get back a valid access token. Also since the JavaScript application already in place works without issue I am assuming that Dynamics 365 is provisioned properly to allow API access.

What I am trying to figure out is what I might be doing wrong within Postman that results in my receiving a 401? What could be different between the working JavaScript request and what I am sending via Postman?

Comment: Can you make sure you are passing the Bearer token as a request header item?

Comment: @ArunVinoth Yes. passed in the heder as `Authorization` `Bearer <token here>`

Comment: Rour resource access url seems to be different when obtaining the token. `https://<company-domain-here>.dynamics.com` vs in your request `https://<company-name>.operations.dynamics.com/`

Comment: @NickGoloborodko Yes, I see what you are saying but is that an issue? The token request URL can be different from the resource URL.

Comment: @webworm The Url is included inside of the token, and unless there is a specific match I'm guessing it could be tripping up the auth machanism in dynamics. Just thought it might be worth a try.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Issue is finally solved.
As mentioned follow the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/developer/common-data-service/webapi/setup-postman-environment) mentioned.

If you face 401 Error, here is the last trick.

In postman Under Authorization--> Add authorization data to--> select Request Headers.

Now fire the query you shall have the 200 ok.

[image]

[Ref](https://rajeevpentyala.com/2019/02/13/step-by-step-postman-tool-to-test-dynamics-365-online-web-api/) Article which helped me figure it out.

Comment: Excellent article thanks for posting the link. I can confirm that the Postman temp headers do include the bearer token so that is not the issue. I think @Nick from the comments above may be onto something. I need to confirm that the URL used to access the API endpoint is the same as the URL encoded in the JWT.