# Connect Dynamics 365 CRM to Databricks

Tags: python, r, pyspark, databricks, dynamics-365

I have a dynamics 365 link which has a lot of data. I can easily connect this link with Power BI and access the data. Now what I'm trying to do is connect this dynamics link directly with Databricks using python/R to get the data. I'm new on working with Databricks and Dynamics 365 kind of stuck on how to move forward.

I've already tried this link:

```
https://alexanderdevelopment.net/post/2016/11/27/dynamics-365-and-python-integration-using-the-web-api/
```

I always get the error cannot get access token. I think the error is in the below statement:

```
tokenres = requests.post(tokenendpoint, data=tokenpost)
```

I think the issue is with tokenendpoint, as I'm not sure what it exactly is and I'm using the what is mentioned in the link. My question is the tokenendpoint correct or does it have to be different, if so how can I find it? If there is any other method to connect Dynamics CRM with python/R to get data. Please let me know.

```
tokenendpoint = 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000/oauth2/token' #oauth token endpoint

tokenpost = {
'client_id':clientid,
'resource':crmorg,
'username':username,
'password':userpassword,
'grant_type':'password'
}
```

I'm sure about all the details in the tokepost.

Comment: why not use api from dynamics 365 api and fetch/get only those data which is required rather than piling your databricks with unnecessary data?

Comment: The quantity of the data is not the issue, I just want to see if I'm able to make the connection. I'm not sure I follow you can you please elaborate on your point.

Comment: [Please refer to article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/customerengagement/on-premises/developer/webapi/setup-postman-environment)

Comment: @AnkUser Thanks, I'll see if this solves my problem.

Comment: @AnkUser, Thanks for the above link, I've done all the steps but as soon as I request access token, it redirects me to the sign in page, I enter my credentials and then just a blank page. I tried finding the error the most obvious answer I got was the callback url could be an issue. I saw lot of people facing the same problem of blank screen. Do you know any alternate tool other than Postman? I tried lot of different Callback URL but that didn't solve the problem.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60279116/5436880 try this link.

Comment: Did you receive any error, I believe you get 401 error I.e unauthorized access. Try above link and let me know.

Comment: I didn't receive any error, Just blank screen. I'll try the above link. I checked in the logs and there it was written "URL did not match the registered callbackURL, so skipping".

Comment: probably you have missed some steps for Config with Postman. reaching dynamics with Postman, Once you do that you can manage next steps

Comment: Nope, I rechecked everything did not miss any steps. :/