# I want to integrate Dynamics CRM with Postman without AAD registration

Tags: dynamics-crm, crm

I want to integrate Dynamics CRM with Postman with the help of username and password and without Azure AD registration.

Comment: What did you try? Share some more details, please.

Comment: I am trying to figure out alternate way for integrating instead of OAuth 2.0 like the azure AD application registration process. Can you please let me know what are the alternate way?

Comment: Is there a reason behind this ? That will help us to help you in right way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is purely dependent on your environment. If it is CRM online or IFD then OAuth is the only choice. The documentation says “must”. [Read more](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/customerengagement/on-premises/developer/webapi/authenticate-web-api?view=op-9-1&WT.mc_id=DX-MVP-5004422#with--or-internet-facing-deployments)

> When you use the Web API for Customer Engagement or an on-premises Internet-facing deployment (IFD) you must use OAuth as described in [Use OAuth with Dataverse](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/developer/common-data-service/authenticate-oauth?WT.mc_id=DX-MVP-5004422).

If it is on-premise then you have to use username/password. [Read more](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/customerengagement/on-premises/developer/webapi/authenticate-web-api?view=op-9-1&WT.mc_id=DX-MVP-5004422#web-api-authentication-with-on-premise-deployments)

> When you use the Web API for on-premises deployments you must include the user’s network credentials.

In case if you are having difficulty with AAD App registration - then you can use the example readymade client Id in documentation for development purpose. [Read more](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60194687)